# Cannot open SCTP Socket

Tags: sockets, sctp

I want to open a basic socket by the below code:

```
SOCKET  s;
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP); 
if(s==INVALID_SOCKET || s == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("%d", errno);
        closesocket(s);
        return SOCKET_INIT_FAILED;
}
```

The errno it returns: 93.

kernel Version: 2.6.18-238.el5
Cent OS: 5.7

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of SCTP sockets: a *one-to-one* socket and a *one-to-many* socket.To create SCTP socket you should specify:

- *one-to-one*: AF_INET family, SOCK_STREAM type and IPPROTO_SCTP protoccol
- *one-to-many*: AF_INET family, SOCK_SEQPACKET type and IPPROTO_SCTP protoccol

Since errno 93 is " Protocol not supported" then try with SOCK_SEQPACKET:

```
int sock_fd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in IPv6 configuration. SCTP protocol implementation needs IPv6 enabled. Once it is enabled, our program working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install lksctp, the error 93 is "Protocol not supported"